# Apache ProxyPassReverse escaping special characters

Tags: apache-2.2, reverse-proxy, mod-proxy

I have this very simple reverse proxy rule in Apache 2.2.19:

```
ProxyPass         /test     http://other.local.machine/test
ProxyPassReverse  /test     http://other.local.machine/test
```

The problem is that it seems mod_proxy escapes the special characters in the `Location` header, but the special characters there are *already* escaped (for example, spaces become `%20`). So, in the end, a simple space is converted into the fugly sequence `%2520`.

The reason why the `Location` headers are already escaped is because they're generated by a `RewriteRule` directive, that escapes characters by default.

How can I fix this?

Comment: What's the `RewriteRule` look like?

Comment: @ShaneMadden Something like `RewriteRule /test.htm  "/test page.html" [R]`. I tried to escape the spaces, but everything gets escaped twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't you just modify your RewriteRule? It has the [NE flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_ne) to prevent escaping of special characters.

```
RewriteRule /test.htm "/test page.html" [NE,R]
```

Comment: I didn't know that, but... It doesn't work, because the *browser* now escapes the spaces, makes its redirected request, and `ProxyPass` escapes the `%`, leading to the exact same result... Oh, the nerves! To be clear, I get *two* "302 Found" pages.

Comment: You can replace your ProxyPass with a RewriteRule as well, using the [P flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_p). I would try that, of course using the NE flag in that rule as well.

Comment: Replaced the `ProxyPass` rule with `RewriteRule /test/(.*) http://other.local.machine/$1 [NE,P]`, and used the `NE` flag in the proxied machine too, but still got the double escape. The problem here is `ProxyPassReverse`, which coulnd't be replaces as easily.

Comment: I think it may all depend on the structure of the local network. It's actually a *double* reverse proxy, so no wonder it must be something tricky. Thank you for your effort to help me, your answer hasn't solved my problem for now... but it may will when I'll try harder. So +1 and answer accepted.

Comment: I don't believe you're supposed to mark questions as answered if it doesn't actually fix the problem.  Did you find a solution?!  I'm having the same problem.